# Explain the plane scene in The Dark Knight Rises?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dark-knight-rises

In The Dark Knight Rises, at the beginning of the film Bane kidnapped a guy from the plane, then he drew blood from the guy he kidnapped. And then throughout the movie I didn't see any news regarding this kidnap scene. But, before the end of the movie we find out that the guy kidnapped by Bane was **Dr Pavel**. Bane needed him to convert the fusion project into a nuclear bomb and Dr Pavel was the only guy who could have done it.

But I don't understand, ***why did he draw blood from Dr Pavel***?

Comment: This blood transfusion confuses me as well. It was intended to disguise the body to make it seem as if it was the doctor from blood tests? First of all they would check fingerprints, dental records, DNA from tissue or hair... Putting a little blood in a random vein that they may or may not check is a joke.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

He wanted the flight crash to make it look like the death of Dr Pavel, so he took the blood from Pavel and put it in other guy so that when they find the bodies after the crash they can confirm the death of pavel by his blood signature.

I think Bane wanted Pavel to be assumed dead because a nuclear scientist missing would bring needless attention to the plan he was forging to destroy Gotham, and I think sooner or later his connection to the scientist could have been exposed if he wasn't assumed to be dead.

There is one specific reference in the movie when Bruce Wayne talks about his nuclear energy project (when he is about to go bankrupt so he tries to market the idea to Miranda to back him) and during the discussion it was mentioned that Pavel was the only guy who could've helped him out with the success of that operation and when Bruce asks about his whereabouts it was revealed to him that he was killed in an air-crash (6 months prior or something, forgot the duration).

Hope it clarifies your question.

Comment: When the CIA agents were taking Dr. Pavel aboard the plane at the start, they mentioned that Bane had been trying to kidnap him and that they were supposed to bring back one of Bane's captured henchmen. They balked at bringing three prisoners onto the plane but the transporters sold them on it by saying they wouldn't cost extra.