# Why doesn't Bane kidnap Dr. Pavel before take-off in The Dark Knight Rises?

Tags: the-dark-knight-rises

In The Dark Knight Rises, in the intro scene, Bane waits to be in the plane to finally kidnap Dr. Pavel by using a *very costly plan*. He could have kidnapped Dr. Pavel before, while he was on the car for example.

I understand from [this explanation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3483/explain-the-plane-scene-in-the-dark-knight-rises)
that Bane wants to hide Dr. Pavel's death. 
So why didn't Bane kidnap Dr Pavel on the ground before take-off? This would have been much more easier and have the exact same advantages.

well, that's still a great intro scene :)

Clarification:
I'm questioning Bane's **strategy** here (Why he did that instead of that) while on this [post](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3483/explain-the-plane-scene-in-the-dark-knight-rises) the question is about **meanings** of Bane's plan (why he's doing that) on the specific action of Dr Pavel's bloods transfer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explain the plane scene in The Dark Knight Rises?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3483/explain-the-plane-scene-in-the-dark-knight-rises)

Comment: Couldn't you use the same argument for Batman's actions, or pretty much anyone in superheroes universes? They're never big on efficiency, but they look *cool* and money is never an issue for them, so the plan being "costly" is irrelevant.

Comment: Nop, Batman has money issue in this movie and Bane has to make an hold up on Wall Street to fund his actions. Even Catwoman steal to make her living. Cost is relvant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dr. Pavel, a Russian nuclear scientist who could turn a nuclear energy source into a destructive time bomb that could wipe out an entire city, was taken into captivity by the American
Military(???) to prevent him from doing the above mentioned thing, willingly or unwillingly.

If Bane abducted Dr. Pavel, then he would be missing and not dead and American security agencies would be looking for him everywhere as they were the first time when they caught Pavel.

By letting Dr. Pavel board the plane, letting Litttlefinger call the base for confirming the transfer and then crashing the plane with no survivors, Bane made sure that the American agencies believed that Dr. Pavel died in the plane crash, courtesy the blood transfusion plot.
So, having confirmed that Dr. Pavel died via blood/DNA test, American security agencies would stop looking for him.

Comment: Huh! Had not realized that the actor from Game of Thrones was in this movie til I read your answer, awesome